# How to resolve the warnings which are getting because of using mongoose query inside loop/recursive function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loops, mongoose, notifications

I was making a notification feature for my project in which I have to update some feilds in a notification collection if user had seen the notification. So I am sending an ObjectIds of those notifications which are seen inside an array in a body feild through a post request. It is glad to see that the code is running and there is an update in mongoDB database but I am getting some warnings in my console.

**My post request function :-**

```
exports.markeNotificationRead = (req,res) => {

function asyncLoop(value){

if(value< req.body.length){
    Notification.updateOne({_id:req.body[value]}, {read: true}).then((doc) => {
        console.log(doc);

        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return res.json({message: "Notification marked read"});
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);

        return res.status(500).json(err);
    });

    asyncLoop(value + 1);

}


}
asyncLoop(0);
}
```

**Warnings :-**

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
at C:\Users\XYZ\PROJECT\handlers\users.js:318:17
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
```

code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

```
(node:25968) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
(node:25968) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\XYZ\PROJECT\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\XYZ\PROJECT\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\XYZ\PROJECT\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at C:\Users\XYZ\PROJECT\handlers\users.js:324:36
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    (node:25968) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
    (node:25968) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have also used foreach loop but still I am getting same warning. So what should I do now.

Comment: keep `if` loop inside `try` block

Comment: Why are you using loop at all? You can update all notifications with a single call using `Notification.update({ _id: { $in: req.body }} , { read: true})....` See docs for `$in` operator https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/
Also the error is caused by multiple calls of `res.json` since this function and some others can only be called once per request. It will close the connection after first call.

Comment: @Molda thank you for your help.